# dynamic domain filter in openerp

Tags: odoo

I have to filter a the properties on the sale order lines based on the property groups.
I want to select a group in sale order line and then in the field property_ids should show the property link the particular group selected.

i added a property group list in sale_stock.py

```
    'group_id': fields.many2one('mrp.property.group', 'Property Group'),
    'property_ids': fields.many2many('mrp.property', 'sale_order_line_property_rel', 'order_id', 'property_id', 'Properties', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}),
```

and i wrote a onchange function

```
    def on_change_group(self, cr, uid, ids, group_id):
    v = {}
    list_data = []
    if group_id:
        group_property_ids = self.pool.get('mrp.property').search(cr, uid, [('group_id', '=', group_id)])
        for record in self.pool.get('mrp.property').browse(cr, uid, group_property_ids):
            list_data.append({'property_id': record.id})
        v['property_ids'] = list_data
        return {'value':v}
```

sale_stock_view.xml

```
    <field name="group_id" widget="selection" on_change="on_change_group(group_id)" />
                   <field name="property_ids" widget="many2many_tags"
                        groups="sale.group_mrp_properties"/>
```

This code doesn't give any error but there is no filter happened in the property field

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using onchange, try domain

```
<field name="property_ids" widget="many2many_tags" domain="[('group_id','=',group_id)]" groups="sale.group_mrp_properties"/>
```